# Why does a material show through another mesh's material?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Why is the plane that is below another mesh showing through it? I have transmission and transparency set to 0 for the materials that are being shown through. When I hide the plane, the material renders fine. However, when the plane is visible, it completely shows through the laptop.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

I am using Blender 2.93.1 with the Eevee engine.

Plane in viewport shows through laptop.
[image]
There does seem to be this sweet spot where it doesn't show through:
[image]
When plane is hidden, the laptop in the viewport looks fine.
[image]
When the plane is not hidden, the render also has the laptop be see through.
[image]
When the plane is hidden in the render, the laptop looks fine.
[image]

The bacon is unaffected as is the keyboard which is coplanar to the plane.

Here is the solid view so you can see the plane is very much below the laptop and not intersecting it.
[image]

Node setup for monitor screen: [image]
Image texture used for monitor screen: [image]
Node setup for terminal screen on laptop: [image]

I haven't been able to find any similar issues to this. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
@CoolCoder
High Quality Normals did not do the trick. Thank you though. [image]
@Chris [Blender File](https://pasteall.org/blend/a47d66b03a0548cf8b43849c9eb4779c)

Comment: Try turning on *High Quality Normals* in *Render Settings>Performance*

Comment: can u please provide blend file?

Comment: If it's EEVEE, you probably have "Alpha Blend" turn it on for that material

Comment: @Emir That fixed the issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the blending method for the plane. It had Alpha Blend turned on. I changed it to Opaque. Everything else has blending bode set to Alpha Blend.
[image]

What it looks like now:
[image]